# A mathematical function that gets us the number of leaves of a specific type of k-ary?

Tags: java, math, tree

I am trying to figure out a function f(x) that would calculate the number of leaves in a k-ary tree. For example, assume we created a tree that began with root 4 with 3 children, each of -1,-2,-3 respectively. Our leaves would only be 0 values, not null values. I have spent the past day trying to figure out a function and it seems like nothing I do goes in the correct direction.

EX:

```
              4
         /    |     \
        3     2      1
     /  |\   /|     /  
    2   1 0 1 0    0  
   /|  /   /
  1 0 0   0
 /
0
```

7 Leaves.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

To clarify, I need a mathematical equation that derives the same answer as code would if I recursively transversed the tree.

More examples:
{4,7}{5,13}{6,24}{7,44}{8,81}{9,149}{10,274}{11,504}{12,927}{13,1705}{14,3136}{15,5768}{16,10609}{17,19513}{18,35890}{19,66012}{20,121415}

```
 public int numleaves(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null)
        return 0; 
    else if (node.getLeft() == null && node.getMiddle() == null && node.getRight() == null)
        return 1; 
    else
        return numleaves(node.getLeft()) + numleaves(node.getMiddle()) + numleaves(node.getRight());
}
```

Comment: So, specifying the current tree-state to be calculated would be quite the trick then?  (You'd need the whole tree, not just k and n, to know how many leaves right)?  (trivially: 1 <= leaves <= logk(n))

Comment: Recursively, count at n = (2 * count at n-1) + 1.
Some of your calculations above are incorrect (I think it should be {5, 15}, for example).

Comment: That doesn't work. `{5,13}` is correct.

Comment: Can you please clarify, you have the recursive code but you'd only be interested in a mathematical derivation of the result?

Comment: If at all possible, yes, for example if we created the tree with a root of 6, I'm looking for a function that if I plugged in x, would give me the accurate number of leaves. I added my recursive method if it at all helps.

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for a non-recursive function that calculates the number of leaves?

Comment: Yes, not code, a mathematical f(x) function. If one is not possible, even an approximation would be close. Basically how do I turn that code into a closed f(x) function with no recursion.

Comment: How do you build this tree? It looks like 3 is split into {2,1,0}, but 4 is only split into {3,2,1} (no 0). 2 has a 0, 1 has 0. Why does 4 not produce {3,2,1,0}? Is there some rule that only <=3 has a 0 child node?

Comment: It can have only 3 children.

Comment: You must mean max of 3? A 3 child requirement isn't observed always as 2 splits into {1,0} not {1,0,-1}.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer your question, but it has a [solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients). I can only outline the case for the number of children `k` being equal to `2`. The case `k=3` leads to a cubic polynomial with two complex and one real solution, I lack the tools here to derive them in a non-numerical way.

But let's have a look at the case `k=2`. Interestingly, this problem is very closely related to the Fibonacci numbers, except for having different boundary conditions.

Writing down the recursive formula is easy:

```
a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2)
```

with boundary conditions `a(1)=1` and `a(0)=1`. The characteristic polynomial of this is

```
x^2 = x + 1
```

with the solutions `x1 = 1/2 + sqrt(5)/2` and `x2 = 1/2 - sqrt(5)/2`. It means that

```
a(n) = u*x1^n + v*x2^n
```

for some `u` and `v` is the explicit formula for the sequence we're looking for. Putting in the boundary conditions we get

```
u = (sqrt(5)+1)/(2*sqrt(5))
v = (sqrt(5)-1)/(2*sqrt(5))
```

i.e.

```
a(n) = (sqrt(5)+1)/(2*sqrt(5))*(1/2 + sqrt(5)/2)^n + (sqrt(5)-1)/(2*sqrt(5))*(1/2 - sqrt(5)/2)^n
```

for `k=2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be computing a [Tribonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Tribonacci_numbers) with starting values `1`, `1` and `2`.  This is [sequence A000073](http://oeis.org/A000073) from the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, starting from the third entry of that sequence rather than the first.  The comments section of the encyclopedia page gives an explicit formula: since this is a linear recurrence relation with a degree 3 characteristic polynomial, there's a closed form solution in terms of the roots of that polynomial.  Here's a short piece of Python 2 code based on the given formula that produces the first few values.  (See the edit below for a simplification.)

```
from math import sqrt

c = (1 + (19 - 3 * sqrt(33))**(1/3.) + (19 + 3 * sqrt(33))**(1/3.)) / 3.
m = (1 - c) / 2
p = sqrt(((3*c - 5)*(c+1)/4))
j = 1/((c-m)**2 + p**2)
b = (c - m) / (2 * p*((c - m)**2 + p**2))
k = complex(-j / 2, b)
r1 = complex(m, p)

def f(n):
    return int(round(j*c**(n+2) + (2*k*r1**(n+2)).real))

for n in range(0, 21):
    print n, f(n)
```

And the output:

```
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 4
4 7
5 13
6 24
7 44
8 81
9 149
10 274
11 504
12 927
13 1705
14 3136
15 5768
16 10609
17 19513
18 35890
19 66012
20 121415
```

---

EDIT: the above code is needlessly complicated.  With the `round` operation, the second term in `f(n)` can be omitted (it converges to zero as `n` increases), and the formula for the first term can be simplified.  Here's some simpler code that generates the same output.

```
s = (19 + 297**0.5)**(1/3.)
c = (1 + s + 4/s)/3
j = 3 - (2 + 1/c)/c
for n in range(0, 32):
    print n, int(round(c**n / j))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help it, but I see Binomial tree in it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap

I think that good approximation could be sum of k-th row of pascal triangle, where k stands for the number of the root node.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this easier to understand:

We set the starting values for the tribonacci sequence into a list called result. Then we put these values into 3 variables. We change the variable content based on the tribonacci formula (new a is a+b+c, new b is old a, new c is old b). Then we calculate to whatever tribonacci number we want to go up to and store each result into our result list. At the end, we read out the indexed list.

```
result=[1,1,2]
a,b,c=result[-1],result[-2],result[-3]
for i in range(40):
    a,b,c=a+b+c,a,b
    result.append(a)
for e,f in enumerate(result):
    print e,f
```